# UPDATE with logical AND operator

Tags: mysql, database

I tried running this sql

```
UPDATE table
SET read = 1
WHERE col1_id = 2
AND col3_id = 1;
```

and it return an error (error in your sql syntax)

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = 1 WHERE team_notification_id = 2 AND listener_id = 1' at line 1

But when I used thesame WHERE and AND :), in a SELECT statement no error was returned.

```
SELECT * 
FROM read
WHERE col1_id = 2 
AND col3_id = 1
```

please what did I do wrong, I am no seeing it.

Comment: DO NOT use reserved words for any naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After keyword UPDATE there should be a table name. If your table has actually name `table` (that's a bit strange) you should escape it to let MySQL know it's not a keyword "table" but actual table name.

The same thing is about `read`.

Both `table` and `read` are MySQL keywords (the full list is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) so if it's your actual table and column names then you should escape it.

Better to escape all table and column names to prevent issues like that.

Escaping in MySQL is done with backtick symbol ` so your query will looks like:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `read` = 1
WHERE `col1_id` = 2
AND `col3_id` = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET `field_name` = 1
WHERE col1_id = 2
AND col3_id = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table
SET [read] = 1
WHERE col1_id = 2
AND col3_id = 1;
```

Comment: This is probably good for SQL Server. MySQL uses backticks to quote the database, table and field names when they contain special characters or conflict with reserved words.

Comment: what axiac said

Comment: in my answer i had used square brackets([]) instead of backticks (`) so he was saying in mysql we use backticks for quoting purpose.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.